# Toast onItemClickListener using string for message?

Tags: android, string, toast

How can I make toast onItemClickListener that use String for message?
I am making app that support multiple languages, and I want to show toast on different languages. For that I need to use Strings. So How can I get string for toast and show it?

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
             int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                showtost();
                break;
              }
            return true;
```

I tried with some methods but it didn't work.

```
private void showtost() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    .getResources().getString(R.string.alarm),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
            }

The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){},
```

String, int)

Comment: Maybe add your current implementation of the onItemClickListener

Comment: U just have to change ur Locale in your app, and get the localised string from the respective strings.xml.

Comment: I cant understand the real question , you need to define string about multi language, or you need to onitemclicklistener for toast?

Comment: I need my toast to use string for message. I read on other threads related to toast with strings and there was said that some codes cannot be used for OnItemClickListener

Comment: can you see my answer? please look ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `this` to be a reference to the context, e.g. if in an activity use:

```
MyActivity.this
```

Or inside a fragment use:

```
getActivity()
```

Then the example you posted will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
Toast.makeText(context, R.string.hello_world, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

here `hello_world` can be replaced with your String ID from the ***strings.xml***.

Answer (score 1):

you have to mention getActivity() over there.

```
private void showtost() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    .getResources().getString(R.string.alarm),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

for multilanguage support;
you can define `strings.xml` in values folder and you can add different folder name as `values-tr`(this is for turkish). and then you can set your string like this:

```
String my_toast_string=context.getString(R.string.my_string);
```

then you can put your toast like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),my_toast_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the string with;

String x= getResources().getString(R.string.language);

and you can make folders in res with language settings and change your string file in there:

folder res/values-cn you make a string file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="language">cn</string>
</resources>
```

and if you make a folder res/values-en you make a string file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="language">en</string>
</resources>
```

and now if you set your Item on a clocklistener and add folowing code:

```
Toast.makeText(context, language, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the output is "cn" if your language device is chinese and "en" if english

i suggest to make a default value in the folder res/values